# Flask url_for()'s argument (e.g. username) values in OTHER LANGUAGES don't work

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building my blog app with Flask.

I want to highlight the active page through menu icon with shadowed text/image.

Basic logic is coded something like:

```
{% if request.path==url_for('main.about') %}
    <li><a class="menu active" href="{{ url_for('main.about') }}">{{ _('About') }}</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li><a class="menu" href="{{ url_for('main.about') }}">{{ _('About') }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

The above works fine. However, when I have an url_for() link that requires an argument value to be inserted e.g. username, it only works if the argument value (=username) was in English but didn't work for Chinese nor Japanese argument values:

```
{% if request.path==url_for('users.user_page', username=current_user.username) %}
    <li><a class="menu active" href="{{ url_for('users.user_page', username=current_user.username) }}">{{ _('Hello') }}{{ User.username}}</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li><a class="menu" href="{{ url_for('users.user_page', username=current_user.username) }}">{{ _('Hello') }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

I thought about URL processors, but lang_code doesn't seem to be the issue here.

After comparing the values suggested by @snakecharmerb, it turned out that the non-English username appeared in URL was garbled.

However, if I try to set the URL in the `if` condition to be :

```
{% if request.path=="/user/" + current_user.username %}
```

it worked.

Like so:
[image]

In my html template, I did include:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Not sure how to proceed from here to resolve this url_for() issue...

Comment: In the non-English case, what are the values of `request.path` and `url_for('users.user_page', username=current_user.username)`? Can you [edit] the question to include the `repr()` of each of them?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks! Now I know why they didn't match. Please see the edited question.